# Issue with Jasmine Unit test for Angular 4 app

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a test case for my angular component, which is basically testing whether a function that is not supposed to be called, was called.

```
describe('...', () => {
...
it('should not call someFunction', function(done) {
   let spy = spyOn(comp, 'someFunction');
   comp.mainFunction();
   fixture.detectChanges();
   expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
   setTimeout(() => {
    expect(comp.someVariable).toBe(false);
    done();
   ),100);
}


mainFunction() {
...
if(condition) {
 this.someFunction();
} else {
 setTimeout( () => {
  this.someVariable = false;
 },100);
}
```

According to the code in the component and the test case in the spec, lets assume `else` is supposed to run. Which means that `someFunction()` should not be called and `someVariable = false` after 100ms. When I run this test, it sometimes passes and sometimes fails. What could be the reason for the test to fail? Is the `setTimeout` causing an issue in the test case? The error that I get when the test fails is

Expected true to be falsy

Comment: Try increasing the timeout duration in your test - both are 100ms but setTimeout isn't exact, so it's possible that sometimes your test is resolving first, but not always.

Comment: @DuncanThacker This worked perfectly. Can you please add this an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing the timeout duration in your test - both are 100ms but setTimeout isn't exact, so it's possible that sometimes your test is resolving first, but not always.